# Bolzano-Weierstrass on two related bounded sequences

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $(x_n),(y_n)$ are two sequences such that (1) $x_n$ are bounded and (2) $|x_n-y_n|<1/n$, where $(x_{n_i})$ is a convergent subsequence of $(x_n)$, is it guaranteed that $(y_{n_i})$ also converges? In other words, is condition (2) enough to ensure that the same sequence of indexes $n_i$ will produce a convergent subsequence of $y_n$?

Here's why I think that's true:

Condition (2) ensures that $|x_{n_i}-y_{n_i}|<1/n_i\overset{i\rightarrow \infty }{\rightarrow}0$ and so $\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty } ( y_{n_i}-x_{n_i} )=0$. So,
$$\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty } y_{n_i} =\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty } (x_{n_i}+ (y_{n_i}-x_{n_i}) )=\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty } x_{n_i}+\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty } (y_{n_i}-x_{n_i})=\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty } x_{n_i}.$$

In particular, $x_{n_i}$ and $y_{n_i}$ have the same limit.

Comment: looks good to me

Answer (score 1):

You can not speak of "$\lim_{i \to \infty} y_{n_i}$" if you have not proven that it is convergent. The following argument would suffice: Let $a = \lim_{i \to \infty} x_{n_i}$. Then,

$ 0 \leq |y_{n_i} - a| = |y_{n_i} + x_{n_i} - x_{n_i} -a |
\leq  |y_{n_i} - x_{n_i}| + |x_{n_i} - a|$.

By the squeeze theorem, it follows that $(y_{n_i})$ is convergent to $a$.

Comment: But doesn't the fact that lim (x) and lim (y-x) exist guarantee the existence of lim (x+(y-x)) = lim y? Or does it?

Comment: I didn't said it did not, I just said you can not speak of the convergence of the sequence if you have not proven it is convergent; you should have stated that in your proof